# Data structure to work with matrix-based problems

Tags: data-structures

I often find myself unsure about what data structure is better for matrix-based algorithms.

By "matrix-based algoritm" I mean algorithms like [Needleman-Wunsh alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Needleman%E2%80%93Wunsch_algorithm). There are many algorithms that are visually represented with a matrix.

I wonder what should I choose:

- Array of arrays
- Linked-list of linked-lists
- Hash table where Key is a tuple like (line, column)
- etc

What do I have to consider when facing this impasse?

Obs: My question is "language-open". You can use any programming language in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What data structure to use depends on your algorithm and how you will access that matrix. For example, If size is fixed and there is a need for fast access, it is better to use 2 dimensional array, because no matter what you use, you will have to allocate that space anyway. If the size of matrix is determined dynamically, then probably vector of vector (or similar data structure depending on language).
Another question is if your matrix is sparse and extremely big(like in digital geometry algorithms) and you have to do arithmetic operations on that matrix very often, then triple format data structures could be useful , for example compressed row storage that could be created using 3 vectors. You can read  more in this link https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressed_Row_Storage 
Hope it helps